# Problem with Earth Engine Python API Implementation

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api, docker

I am trying to use the Python Earth Engine API to run an application. This application is already in production and I am trying to migrate it to a new server. It runs in a Docker Container and uses Herokuapp and GUnicorn as the server.

The problem is whenever I try to run the Docker image, I get the following error. It seems to come from Earth Engine but I cannot pin down why it is occurring.

```
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
[2022-05-18 00:09:02 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2022-05-18 00:09:03 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 190, in init_process
    super(GeventWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 96, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/appuser/app/croplands-api/herokuapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from croplands_api import create_app
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 96, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/appuser/app/croplands-api/croplands_api/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ee
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 96, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import batch
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 96, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/batch.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import data
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 96, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/appuser/app/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 611
    lambda x, y, z: f'{_tile_base_url}/{version}/{name}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}')
                                                                         ^
```

Comment: You're trying to run python 3 code with python 2.7.

Comment: @user2856 Thank you